# Inheritance with generics java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, overriding

I am having issues with my subclasses and trying to make my function "method" generic, please see below, I am having issues implementing classes C1 and C2 to use my objects of type B1 and B2 respectively.

Edit: Sorry if it isn't clear, basically I am trying to override the function method, but I need the parameter to be generic, so for class C1 which is a subclass of C it should use B1 as a parameter and for C2 which is a subclass of C1 it should use B2 as a parameter.

The code the behavior that I am looking to achieve but I am struggling to make it compile.

Here are my classes

```
class A{}
class T1{}
class V1{}
abstract class B<T extends T1, V extends V1>{}
class B1 extends B<SomeChildOfT1, SomeChildOfV1>{}
class B2 extends B1{}

abstract class C <E extends B<? extends T1, ? extends T2>> extends A
{
    void method(E)
      {//bla}
}

class C1<E extends B1> extends C<B1>
{
   //method with object B1 as parameter
   @override
   void method(E){
    //bla
    } 
}

class C2 extends C2<B2>
{
    @override
  void method(B2)
  {

  }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your solution? Call Stacks, Error messages?

Comment: Your question could be presented better. At best, this code won't even compile.

Comment: It's always good to at least mention what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I cannot use an Object of type B2 as a parameter for my method that I overridden in class C2. It works with B1 as a parameter which is not what I need since I use a object of type B2 inside my method.

Comment: What are `T1` and `V1` in `abstract class B<T extends T1, V extends V1>{}`? Can it just be `abstract class B<T, V>{}`?

Comment: can you use this class C1<E extends B1> extends C<? extends B1>
or where is C2 extends with C1

Comment: Tej, it won't compile. I get The type C1 cannot extend or implement C<? extends B1>. A supertype may not specify any wildcard

Comment: -1 for removing the question without reason, after getting the answer

Answer (score 0):

Though it is kind of messy, I think you should do something like:

```
class A{}
class T1{}
class V1{}
abstract class B<T extends T1, V extends V1>{}
class B1 extends B<SomeChildOfT1, SomeChildOfV1>{}
class B2 extends B1{}

abstract class C <T extends T1, V extends V1, E extends B<T, V>> extends A
{
    void method(E)
      {//bla}
}

class C1<E extends B1> extends C<SomeChildOfT1, SomeChildOfV1, E>
{
   //method with object B1 as parameter
   @override
   void method(E){
    //bla
    } 
}

class C2 extends C1<B2>
{
    @override
  void method(B2)
  {

  }
}
```

Comment: Tried this, it comes up to the same thing I had.

When generating override method for C1, the parameter is set to B1.
THen when you generate the override for C2, it uses B1 as a parameter instead of B2 (which is what I am trying to achieve)

Comment: changed a bit on the declaration of C1.  I am not sure if it works though but the previous one is obviously incorrect

Comment: have tried that in ideone, and my suggested way compiles. You may look into http://ideone.com/XK07j7 .  Honestly I think your example is overly complicated...

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't make `C1< E >` extend `C< E >`?  The following compiles for me with suitable edits to your sample:

```
class A{}
class T1{}
class SomeChildOfT1 extends T1 {}
class V1{}
class SomeChildOfV1 extends V1 {}
abstract class B<T extends T1, V extends V1>{}
class B1 extends B<SomeChildOfT1, SomeChildOfV1>{}
class B2 extends B1{}

abstract class C <E extends B<? extends T1, ? extends V1>> extends A {
    void method(E e) {}
}

class C1<E extends B1> extends C<E> {
    @Override void method(E e) {}
}

class C2 extends C1<B2> {
    @Override void method(B2 b2) {}
}
```